# Owin middleware could not registered with Autofac

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, autofac

In my project, I'm using the web api 2, autofac, in the controller I inject to it, everything works fine until I installed The Owin to project, when I run project and navigate to the controller that threw me the error:
**"An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'AccountController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor."**
Here is my code:

The AccountController.cs:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Account")]
public class AccountController : ApiControllerBase
{
     private readonly IAccountService _accountService;

     public AccountController(IAccountService accountService,
         IEntityBaseRepository<Error> errorsRepository)
        : base(errorsRepository)
    {
        _accountService = accountService;
    }

    // POST api/Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(UserModel userModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        IdentityResult result = await _repo.RegisterUser(userModel);

        IHttpActionResult errorResult = GetErrorResult(result);

        if (errorResult != null)
        {
            return errorResult;
        }

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureOAuth(app);
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }

    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

    }

}
```

AutofacWebApiConfig.cs:

```
public class AutofacWebapiConfig
{
    public static IContainer Container;
    public static void Initialize(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        Initialize(config, RegisterServices(new ContainerBuilder()));
    }

    public static void Initialize(HttpConfiguration config, IContainer container)
    {
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    }

    private static IContainer RegisterServices(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        // EF BasicCommerceContext
        builder.RegisterType<BasicCommerceContext>()
               .As<DbContext>()
               .InstancePerRequest();

        builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>()
            .As<IDbFactory>()
            .InstancePerRequest();

        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>()
            .As<IUnitOfWork>()
            .InstancePerRequest();

        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EntityBaseRepository<>))
               .As(typeof(IEntityBaseRepository<>))
               .InstancePerRequest();

        // Services
        builder.RegisterType<EncryptionService>()
            .As<IEncryptionService>()
            .InstancePerRequest();

        builder.RegisterType<MembershipService>()
            .As<IMembershipService>()
            .InstancePerRequest();

        builder.RegisterType<ProductCategoryService>()
           .As<IProductCategoryService>()
           .InstancePerRequest();

        builder.RegisterType<ProductService>()
           .As<IProductService>()
           .InstancePerRequest();

        builder.RegisterType<NewsCategoryService>()
           .As<INewsCategoryService>()
           .InstancePerRequest();

        builder.RegisterType<NewsService>()
           .As<INewsService>()
           .InstancePerRequest();

        builder.RegisterType<CustomerService>()
           .As<ICustomerService>()
           .InstancePerRequest();

        builder.RegisterType<StaticService>()
           .As<IStaticService>()
           .InstancePerRequest();

        // Generic Data Repository Factory
        builder.RegisterType<DataRepositoryFactory>()
            .As<IDataRepositoryFactory>().InstancePerRequest();

        Container = builder.Build();

        return Container;
    }
}
```

Please support me to register or config OWIN with Autofac.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps

1. Reference the Autofac.Owin package from NuGet.
2. Build your Autofac container.
3. Register the Autofac middleware with OWIN and pass it the container.

Documentation is available [here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/owin.html)